# How can I make it more efficient to sweep hair?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I want to make a scene where I sweep hairs with hands.
[image]

It's a picture of a scene that I want to direct.

I thought of three ways, but there are problems with all of them.
First up, It is hair rigging. but it is hard to rig all of hair.
I made hair by curve and count of hair is 30, 30x3bone, need 90bone. it's too mnay bone

second, hair sim. There aren't that many lectures, and there's a high possibility that it won't come out naturally.

third, just modeling. Make a pose to put your hair back and make hairs according to that.
There's a disadvantage that it can't be recycled.

My problem is that I don't know how to make a scene where I sweep hairs.

Comment: You can handle hair particles with curves. Search for it on YouTube. You can animate the curves with shapekeys.

Comment: I'll look for it. Thank you for your answer.